# Add toggle to jQuery mouseover event to trigger CSS color change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, toggle, event-listener

I have below script that works fine when the mouse is hover over the `#eventID` then the `#targetID` text color turns purple. I hope to add a toggle to the script so that when `mouseout` the text color changes back to its original or defined color.

```js
$("#eventID").on ("mouseover",function(){
  $("#targetID").css("color","purple");
})
```

I tried to add the toggle before the css function and before the jQuery event listener, but neither of them works.

*Test1:*

```js
$("#eventID").on ("mouseover mouseout",function(){
  $("#targetID").toggle(css("color","purple"));})
```

*Test2:*

```js
$("#eventID").toggle(on("mouseover mouseout", function() {
  $("#targetID").css("color", "purple");}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
$("#eventID").on("mouseover", function() { 
   $("#targetID").css("color","purple");
}).on("mouseout", function() {
   $("#targetID").css("color","");
});
```

This will clear the inline color style. when you mouseout.